# How to post a JSON object array onto mongodb?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a workout management app which allows a coach (userType = true) to create a workout for the user.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to format my mongodb schema in order to receive the number of exercises.  My idea was to create an array of JSON objects which I would then push onto the database to later display to the user.  The problem is I am at a loss on how to properly create a form which would allow the data to be parsed properly.  I decided to create several forms and then convert them to JSON objects using the .serializeObject() method in JQuery and then push them onto an array.  However I don't know how to push that arrray onto mongoDB

Here is my gym.hbs file

```
<div id ="createWorkout" class="hiddenWorkout workoutCreator">
      <form id="exerciseForm" class="gymFormPadding" action="/dashboard/gym" method="POST">
    <div id="exerciseInput" class="form-group" style="display:flex;width:100%">
        <input id="exerciseName" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Exercise Name" value=""/>        
        <input id="exerciseSets" class="form-control" type="number" name="sets" placeholder="Sets" value=""/>        
        <input id="exerciseReps" class="form-control" type="number" name="reps" placeholder="Reps" value=""/>        
        <input id="exerciseWeight" class="form-control" type="number" name="weight" placeholder="Weight" value="" /> 

      </div>
      </form>
      <div id="newExerciseAdd"></div>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{cybersecurity}}">           
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addExerciseAdd">Add New Exercise</button>               
    <button id="submitWorkout" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"  name="upload">Submit Workout</button>     

    </div>
```

this is the JQuery responsible for the operations

```
  var counter = 1;
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#createWorkout").click(function(){
            $(".hiddenWorkout").removeClass('hiddenWorkout'); 
            $("#createWorkout").hide();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var i = 0;
        $("#addExerciseAdd").click(function(){
          if(i<9){
            $("#exerciseForm").clone().appendTo("#newExerciseAdd");
            i++;
            $("#newExerciseAdd #exerciseForm").attr("id","exerciseForm"+i);
            $("#newExerciseAdd #exerciseInput").attr("id","exerciseInput"+i);
            $("#newExerciseAdd #exerciseName").attr("id","exerciseName"+i);
            $("#newExerciseAdd #exerciseSets").attr("id","exerciseSets"+i);
            $("#newExerciseAdd #exerciseReps").attr("id","exerciseReps"+i);
            $("#newExerciseAdd #exerciseWeight").attr("id","exerciseWeight"+i);
            counter++;
            }

        });

    });


   $(document).ready(function(){
      var array = [];
      var object;
      var exerciseNo = exerciseNo;
        $("#submitWorkout").click(function(){
          $("#exerciseForm").attr("id","exerciseForm0");
          $("#exerciseInput").attr("id","exerciseInput0");
          $("#exerciseName").attr("id","exerciseName0");
          $("#exerciseSets").attr("id","exerciseSets0");
          $("#exerciseReps").attr("id","exerciseReps0");
          $("#exerciseWeight").attr("id","exerciseWeight0");
          for(var i=0;i<counter;i++){
          object=$("#exerciseForm"+i).serializeObject();
          array.push(object);
          }
        });
        console.log(array);
    });
```

this is my controller.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Gym = require('../models/gym');




exports.getGymPage = async (req, res) =>
{
    let coachStatus = req.user.userType;
    let teamID = null;
    if(res.locals.team){teamID = res.locals.team._id}   
    let exercises = await Gym.find({teamId:teamId});
    res.render('/dashboard/gym.hbs',{title: "Gym",exercises : exercises, coachStatus : coachStatus, cybersecurity: `${req.csrfToken()}`});
};

exports.addExercise = (req, res) =>
{
    const exercise = new Gym({teamID:res.locals.team._id, name: req.body.exerciseName,sets:req.body.exerciseSets,reps:req.body.exerciseReps,weight:req.body.exerciseWeight,cybersecurity: `${req.csrfToken()}`}).save();
    res.redirect('/dashboard/gym');
}
```

and this is my models.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const gymSchema = new Schema({
    teamID : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
    },

exercises:[{
    name :{ type:String, require: true},
    sets : [],
    reps : { type: Number, require: true},
    weight : { type: Number,},

}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Gym', gymSchema);
```

is my method of pushing the files completely absurd?  I feel like I'm spinning in circles and getting nowhere with it.  Is there a much better method of doing this?
Please excuse my most likely horrendous code, I'm only starting out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB should know it is an array of data. Have you tried accessing the exercise by doing this for eg...:

```
const exercise = req.body.exercise[0].name;
const exerciseData = JSON.parse(exercise);
```

And then to push, you can just use regular array.push
I don't fully understand what you are trying to do however hope this can be of some help...